# Stop malware(?) in Google Chrome popping up black boxes advertising, ironically "Chrome Users? get rid of Popups Instantly"

Tags: google-chrome, malware, popups

I remotely admin an Ubuntu Linux 18.04 system for an elderly family member. They use the system only for viewing webpages and reading webmail. The browser is Google Chrome.

Somehow they've picked up a malicious something in the browser that keeps popping up black rectangular windows advertising "Chrome Users? Get Rid of Popups Instantly". The other text in the window is a link to "beinspirationaldaily dot com" and a nonclickable line of text "guard.io"

I'm a fairly experienced Linux user but I have very little experience with Google Chrome. The "Don't Allow sites to send pop-ups" is turned ON, and there are no add-ons installed except Social Fixer.

How to troubleshoot and eliminate this problem?

Comment: Have you installed uBlock Origin yet? An ad-blocker is very important on the internet these days.

Comment: It's looking like these are "notifications".  No wonder I don't use Chrome.